# Manipulating vector values using R

Tags: mysql, r, vector

I need help to manipulate vector values.

```
listID <- c(to_del$UnitCode_correct)
print(paste("Update unit set isDeleted=1 where UnitId in(",paste("'",listID,"'", collapse = " ,"),paste(")")))
```

Out put is ...

```
"Update unit set isDeleted=1 where UnitId in( ' SOD0390306 ',' SOD0370274 ',' SOD0370275 ',' SOD0370276 ',' SOD0370277 ',' SOD0410257 ',' SOD0410256 ',' SOD0410255 ',' SOD0410258 ',' SOD0240282 ',' SOD0420517 ')"
```

Now I need to remove those **extra spaces** from the each of the ids (ex - ' SOD0390306 ',' SOD0370274 ' should be like 'SOD0390306','SOD0370274',)

I tried hard to do this but could not be able to fix this. also let me know if there is another way to do this..

Comment: Use `paste0`, or `paste("tralalala",sep="")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sep="" and collapse="," in `paste` as in below code:

```
listID <- c('SOD0390306','SOD0370274','SOD0370275','SOD0370276','SOD0370277','SOD0410257','SOD0410256','SOD0410255','SOD0410258','SOD0240282','SOD0420517')
print(paste("Update unit set isDeleted=1 where UnitId in (",paste("'",listID,"'", collapse = ",", sep=""),paste(")"), sep=""))
```

The output is:

```
"Update unit set isDeleted=1 where UnitId in ('SOD0390306','SOD0370274','SOD0370275','SOD0370276','SOD0370277','SOD0410257','SOD0410256','SOD0410255','SOD0410258','SOD0240282','SOD0420517')"
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: yes, `sep=""` was missing from the code. Just need clarification about which is the best way to do it  `paste0`  or add `sep=""` argument in the code?